# String || comparison operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, comparison-operators

I am new to Ruby and am trying to practice by coding up a simple TicTacToe game.

I have just run into a small issue with the evaluation of if a player has won the game.

Essentially the game works with a board that is equal to:

```
board = ["#",' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
```

Every time a player moves their "marker" (X or O) is added to the board and there are functions to check if the spot is taken, if it is a draw or if a player has won.

So an interim board might look something like this:

```
board = ["#",' ',' ','O',' ','X',' ','O',' ',' ']
```

My issue is coming when evaluating if someone won. I have written a function for this: (the first 3 expressions check for a horizontal win, the next 3 a vertical win and the following 2 look for diagonal wins.

```
def check_for_win(board)
  if [board[1],board[2],board[3]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] || [board[4],board[5],board[6]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] ||
    [board[7],board[8],board[9]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] || [board[1],board[4],board[7]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] ||
    [board[5],board[2],board[8]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] || [board[6],board[9],board[3]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] ||
    [board[1],board[5],board[9]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] || [board[7],board[5],board[3]].uniq == [("X" || "O")] 
    true
  else
    false
  end 
end
```

This function seems to evaluate if there is a winner with the "X" marker, but for the "O" marker if cannot evaluate to true. It should be noted that the left side of the expression still evaluates to what I want it to, for example:

```
board = ["#",' ',' ','O',' ','O',' ','O',' ',' ']
p [board[7],board[5],board[3]].uniq 
>> ["O"]
```

I can not seem to understand why and any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[("X" || "O")]` will always evaluate to a single-element array `["X"]`. Which, I'm guessing is not what you're after.

Comment: I want it to evaluate to check if either of these "markers" are equal to the left side of the expression. Is that possible?

Maybe if you explained why, that would help me out a little...

Comment: "truthy" and "falsey" values, ruby calls this. Anything that is not `nil` or `false` is considered truthy. That's why here `"X"` is selected always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'X' || 'O'` just says X or O. And since any string is truthy it always returns X. So any spot where you’ve said `[('X' || 'O')]`, you’ve really just said `['X']`.

Because of this, you’re only ever checking if a whole line of 3 is all X.

I don’t really understand how you’re trying to test this, but I feel like you’d be better off running the function twice first handing in X and then handing in O if it didn’t find X as a winner, as opposed to trying to check both as once.

Alternatively you could instead have the function return 'X', 'O', or nil and then you could have it only run the function once. The string returned would be who won and if it’s nil then no one won. I would also recommend making a loop for this. I find it easier to read.

Here's how I would solve the problem.

```
ROWS = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],

  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  [3,6,9],

  [1,5,9],
  [7,5,3],
]

def find_winner(board)
  ROWS.each do |row|
    # subtract 1 because the ROWS is 1-indexed (like a phone dial) but arrays are 0-indexed
    row_values = row.map { |v| board[v - 1] }
    return('X') if row_values.all?('X')
    return('O') if row_values.all?('O')
  end

  return(nil)
end


test1 = [
  'X', 'X', 'X',
  'O', 'X', 'O',
  'O', 'O', '',
]
puts "Winner of test1: #{find_winner(test1).inspect}"
"X"

test2 = [
  'X', '',  'X',
  'X', 'O', 'O',
  'X', 'O', 'X',
]
puts "Winner of test2: #{find_winner(test2).inspect}"
"X"

test3 = [
  'O', 'X', 'X',
  'O', 'X', 'O',
  'O', 'O', '',
]
puts "Winner of test3: #{find_winner(test3).inspect}"
"O"

test4 = [
  'O', 'X', 'O',
  'X', 'O', 'X',
  'O', 'O', 'X',
]
puts "Winner of test4: #{find_winner(test4).inspect}"
"O"

test5 = [
  'O', 'X', 'O',
  'O', 'X', 'O',
  'X', 'O', 'X',
]
puts "Winner of test5: #{find_winner(test5).inspect}"
nil
```

Comment: Thank you, that was silly of me. I am passing in the "Marker" to the function now, as on each players turn all you have to do is check if that player has won. Cheers for the pointers.

Comment: No problem! I just edited my post and added what I would do code-wise with some tests.

Comment: You can also use `all?('X')` / `all?('O')`

Comment: I see that all? does allow you to specify a single argument which it will then use to see if all elements === it. I’m not super familiar with the === operator. I’ll check that out later today. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F

Comment: Good call @Stefan

Comment: Consider making the values in `ROWS` offsets into `board` (I.e. base `0`). Among other things, you could then write `row_values = board.values_at(*row)`.

Comment: Although it has no bearing on your question, note that [Array#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-all-3F) has been added in v2.6.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Enumerable has had `all?` since 2.0.0 (at least). https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F I'm not sure why Array hasn't documented that you can use it until recently. But, I did just try it on `2.5.1` (I have that installed) and `all?` worked fine. I can't speak for sure on when it was added.

Comment: Oh, you know what! I'll bet you Ruby 2.6.0 brought forth a performance optimization by giving Array its own custom implementation of `all?` instead of using the generic Enumerable one.

Comment: Yes, I expect that's the reason as the behaviour seems the same as `Enumerable#all?`.

Answer (score 2):

@Nate has answered your question. Here is one way you could write your method.

**Code**

```
def check_for_win(board)
  check_rows(board)                              ||
  check_rows(board.transpose)                    ||
  check_rows([[0,1,2].map { |i| board[i][i] }])  ||    
  check_rows([[0,1,2].map { |i| board[i][2-i] }])
end

def check_rows(rows)
  rows.find { |row| row.uniq.size == 1 && row.first != :_ }&.first
end
```

`&` in `check_rows` is the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). It causes `.first` to be disregarded and `nil` returned if `find`'s block returns `nil`.

**Examples**

```
check_for_win [[:O, :_, :O],
               [:O, :X, :_],
               [:X, :X, :X]]
  #=> :X

check_for_win [[:O, :_, :O],
               [:O, :X, :X],
               [:O, :X, :X]]
  #=> :O

check_for_win [[:X, :O, :X],
               [:O, :X, :O],
               [:O, :X, :X]]
  #=> :X

check_for_win [[:X, :O, :O],
               [:X, :O, :_],
               [:O, :X, :X]]
  #=> :O

check_for_win [[:X, :O, :X],
               [:X, :O, :O],
               [:O, :X, :X]]
  #=> nil

check_for_win [[:_, :_, :_],
               [:X, :O, :O],
               [:O, :X, :X]]
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Nice answer as always Cary. Your answers always teach me new tricks. This time it was the `transpose` method.

Comment: @Nate, I'm happy to have helped.

Comment: Checking via `row.uniq.size == 1` might return the empty field `:_` as a false positive.

Comment: @Stefan, it's curious that nobody noticed that boo-boo before. Thanks.